# How to iterate through a pattern and returns a list of all the strings

Tags: sml, smlnj

Hello i am currently doing the course Programing languages and am having difficulties with the following helper function: The function takes a pattern and returns a list of all the strings it uses for variables.
This is the pattern:

```
 datatype pattern = Wildcard
         | Variable of string
         | UnitP
         | ConstP of int
         | TupleP of pattern list
         | ConstructorP of string * pattern
```

For example:

```
val test1007 = helper (ConstructorP("x", (TupleP [Wildcard, Variable "x", ConstructorP("y", TupleP [Variable "y"])]))) = ["x","y"]
```

I know i have to use some case expression to match for the pattern, but cannot figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Well i had it figured by myself that i have to use case expression, but the problem is that i cannot have no idea what to do afterwards.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you anyway

Comment: If you cannot have no idea what to do, does that mean you must have some idea?